# bash script on specific URL string manipulation

Tags: bash

I need to manipulate a string (URL) of which I don't know lenght.

the string is something like

https://x.xx.xxx.xxx/dontcare1/dontcare2/dontcareN/keyword/restofstring

I basically need a regular expression which returns this:

https://x.xx.xxx.xxx/keyword/restofstring
where the x is the current ip which can vary everytime and I don't know the number of dontcares.

I actually have no idea how to do it, been 2 hours on the problem but didn't find a solution.

thanks!

Comment: Good that you are putting effort to solve your own problem, on SO we do encourage all members to add their efforts in their posts, so kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: There are a lot of answers here. If one of them solved your problem you should accept it. If your problem wasn't solved, edit your question and point out why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` as follows:

```
sed -E 's=(https://[^/]*).*(/keyword/.*)=\1\2='
```

`s` stands for substitute and has the form `s=`*search pattern*`=`*replacement pattern*`=`.
The search pattern is a regex in which we grouped `(...)` the parts you want to extract.
The replacement pattern accesses these groups with `\1` and `\2`.

You can feed a file or stdin to `sed` and it will process the input line by line.
If you have a string variable and use `bash`, `zsh`, or something similar you also can feed that variable directly into stdin using `<<<`.

Example usage for bash:

```
input='https://x.xx.xxx.xxx/dontcare1/dontcare2/dontcareN/keyword/restofstring'
output="$(sed -E 's=(https://[^/]*).*(/keyword/.*)=\1\2=' <<< "$input")"
echo "$output" # prints https://x.xx.xxx.xxx/keyword/restofstring
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "https://x.xx.xxx.xxx/dontcare1/dontcare2/dontcareN/keyword/restofstring" | sed "s/dontcare[0-9]\+\///g"`

[sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) is used to manipulate text. `dontcare[0-9]\+\///g` is an escaped form of the regular expression `dontcare[0-9]+/`, which matches the word "dontcare" followed by 1 or more digits, followed by the `/` character.

sed's pattern works like this: `s/find/replace/g`, where g is a command that allowed you to match more than one instance of the pattern.

You can see that regular expression in action [here](https://regexr.com/4d32t).

Note that this assumes there are no `dontcareN`s in the rest of the string. If that's the case, [Socowi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902530/1256113)'s answer works better.

Comment: That is correct, but we replacing `dontcare` with any string should work. For `\+`, I had to escape it locally for the command to work correctly. According to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html it might be interpreted as an arithmetic operator, but it also clearly says that it should work here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html#PLUSREF

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't think of the difference between `sed` and `sed -E`. For `sed -E` `\+` is a literal, but for `sed` it's a quantifier. However, *"replacing `dontcare` with any string"* might be a bit harder than it seems. I guess OP expects to match anything other than `keyword` instead of `dontcare`, so you have to invert the regex `/keyword/` which is not so easy in `sed`.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. I am not exactly sure what is the approach explained by the OP here, then. If the intention is to target the position of `/keyword/`, then your answer is correct (and mine isn't), but if the intention is to find `/dontcareN/` then mine should work. The format of the question doesn't clearly explain which is intended, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `read` with a `/` value for `$IFS` to parse out the trash.

```
$: IFS=/ read proto trash url trash trash trash keyword rest <<< "https://x.xx.xxx.xxx/dontcare1/dontcare2/dontcareN/keyword/restofstring"
$: echo "$proto//$url/$keyword/$rest"
https://x.xx.xxx.xxx/keyword/restofstring
```

This is more generalized when the `dontcare...` values aren't known and predictable strings.

This one is pure bash, though I like [Socowi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902530/1256113) better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` variation which picks out the host part and the last two components from the path.

```
url='http://example.com:1234/ick/poo/bar/quux/fnord'
newurl=$(echo "$url" | sed 's%\(https*://[^/?]*[^?/]\)[^ <>'"'"'"]*/\([^/ <>'"''"]*/^/ <>'"''"]*\)%\1\2%')
```

The general form is `sed 's%pattern%replacement%'` where the *pattern* matches through the end of the host name part (captured into one set of backslashed parentheses) then skips through the penultimate slash, then captures the remainder of the URL including the last slash; and the *replacement* simply recalls the two captured groups without the skipped part between them.